# Proving a Function Continuous with Non-Standard Analysis

Tags: continuity, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

I am reading a text on non-standard analysis.  I need to prove the following:  Suppose that $f$ is non-decreasing on the real interval $[a,b]$ and that $f$ satisfies the intermediate value property.  Then $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

I need to show this by showing if $y-x$ is infinitesimal, then so is $f(y)-f(x)$.

My first attempt was to pick $c$ so that $f(c)-f(x)\leq y-x$ (for $y>x$).  If $c \geq y$, then
$$
0\leq f(y)-f(x) \leq f(c) - f(x) \leq y-x.
$$
Since $y-x$ is infinitesimal, so is $f(y)-f(x)$.  If $c \leq y$, that argument doesn't work and I am unable to see how to fix it.

My second thought was to use the fact, for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there are $x=x_1, \ldots, x_n=y$ so that
$$
f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k) \leq \varepsilon.
$$
Then
$$
f(y)-f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k) \leq n\varepsilon.
$$
The transfer principle applies, but then I am left with a sum in $^*\mathbb{N}$, and I don't see why it should be infinitesimal.

Are there any ways to complete either of my arguments?  Or, would someone give me a hint in the right direction?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(t)$ is not continuous on $[a,b]$ then there are infinitely close points $x<y\in{}^{\ast}[a,b]$ where $f(x)-f(y)$ is appreciable (i.e., noninfinitesimal).  Let $c=st(x)=st(y)\in [a,b]$, let $K=st(f(x))$ and $L=st(f(y))$ so that $K<L$.  Then $f(t)\leq K$ for all (real) points $t\in [a,c)$ and $f(t)\geq L$ for all $t\in (c,b]$. For the intermediate value theorem to hold,  $f(c)$ would have to take all the values in the interval $(K,L)$, contradiction.

Comment: How do you know that $f(t)<M$ or $f(t)>M$ for the appropriate $t$?

Comment: Because the function is monotone!  I will elaborate in the question.